# Database timestamps in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Creating a database table in MySQL. I have created two fields to grab timestamps.

```
created_at          timestamp default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
updated_at          timestamp default now() on update now(),
```

When I update the database, both fields are updating to the current timestamp. Any thoughts on how to prevent this from happening?  I am not providing the 'created_at' field when I update -- I am also providing 'null' for the updated_at field to auto update.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. What version of MySQL?

Comment: I believe mysql v5.6.4 -- trying to confirm.

Comment: Take a look at the section about timestamps in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of MySQL you should be able to use the following for your default value on the updated_at field:

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Your created_at field should just have CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default.

I would also set both to the datatype datetime instead of timestamp.

Comment: He doesn't want it to default to the current time, he wants it to default to time 0.

Comment: @Barmar - I see that his current declaration is to not have a date-time value for created_at, but that is worthless.  He needs to have it default to the current date-time value when created.  The other option is to change the datatype to datetime and default to NULL.

Comment: @ReubenBrown The code above is something I discovered while trying to get this to work. I can't have two current_timestamp(or now()) declarations without getting an error. I'd really like this to be an automatic thing -- would prefer not to feed the current timestamp upon creation.

Comment: @Spencer-Rohan : I see from an earlier comment you are on MySQL 5.6.4.  I have a database table on the Community version 5.6.23 and it lets me have the exact declaration that I suggested.  It initializes both fields to the current date/time value and then on update it only updates the second field.  You should not try to supply a value on update to either field since they are being managed by the database.

You may want to set the created_at field to "datetime" instead of timestamp to see if it gives you better results.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp initialisation can be an ugly beast in mysql!

Based on the commment below you have mysql v5.6.4 or earlier:

> I can't have two current_timestamps declared without getting an error -- and although it's default is 0 -- it is producing a current timestamp upon creation(without me feeding in the timestamp) – Spencer Rohan

You can have a single timestamp field that are initialised and/or updated to the current timestamp when you insert / update your record. In earlier versions this had to be the 1st timestamp field in the table.

I would simply set the `created_at` to be a nullable column with a default value of null because according to mysql documentation on [timestamp initialization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> In other words, a TIMESTAMP column defined to permit NULL values auto-initializes only if its definition includes DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

By changing the default value to null you go around any problems you may have with zero dates and various sql modes.

```
created_at          timestamp null default null,
```

Comment: I can't have two current_timestamps declared without getting an error -- and although it's default is 0 -- it is producing a current timestamp upon creation(without me feeding in the timestamp)

Comment: "I can't have two current_timestamps declared without getting an error" - so you are using mysql v5.6.4 or earlier version. I'll update my answer accordingly. Although the point of my answer around the nullability still stands.

Comment: Your solution is leaving a value of NULL

Comment: That's what it is supposed to do, if you pass null to the timestamp field. You are passing a null value, that's what caused it to be set to the current_timestamp in the first place.